# Is it possible to remove the stroke from being displayed from within the filter only?

Tags: svg

I am trying to figure out what I need to change in the SVG below to remove the stroke entirely from the filter? I want to keep the  element as it is, I just want the stroke removed from the filter, in the most simple way, and I can't seem to figure out if this is even possible?

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="640" height="480" viewBox="0 0 640 480" xml:space="preserve">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="640" height="480" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)"></rect>
    <filter id="SVGID_3" y="-20%" height="140%" x="-82%" width="264%">
     <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="0"></feGaussianBlur>
     <feOffset dx="100" dy="0" result="oBlur"></feOffset>
     <feFlood flood-color="rgb(221, 221, 221)"></feFlood>
     <feComposite in2="oBlur" operator="in"></feComposite>
     <feMerge>
      <feMergeNode></feMergeNode>
      <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
     </feMerge>
    </filter>
    <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="81" style="stroke: rgb(0,0,0); stroke-width: 36; stroke-dasharray: 7 7; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: bevil; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(255,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;filter: url(#SVGID_3);" transform="translate(213 86.2) "></circle>
</svg>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer is no.  You could make the black parts transparent, but it would leave the red circle with chunks missing where the stroke used to be.  I doubt that is what you want.

However if you mean "how do I achieve that effect by altering this SVG", then the answer would be to duplicate the circle and give one the fill and the filter, and the other the stroke.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="640" height="480" viewBox="0 0 640 480" xml:space="preserve">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="640" height="480" fill="rgba(255,255,255,1)"></rect>
    <filter id="SVGID_3" y="-20%" height="140%" x="-82%" width="264%">
     <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="0"></feGaussianBlur>
     <feOffset dx="100" dy="0" result="oBlur"></feOffset>
     <feFlood flood-color="rgb(221, 221, 221)"></feFlood>
     <feComposite in2="oBlur" operator="in"></feComposite>
     <feMerge>
      <feMergeNode></feMergeNode>
      <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
     </feMerge>
    </filter>
    <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="81" style="fill: rgb(255,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;filter: url(#SVGID_3);" transform="translate(213 86.2) "></circle>
    <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="81" style="stroke: rgb(0,0,0); stroke-width: 36; stroke-dasharray: 7 7; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: bevel; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: none;" transform="translate(213 86.2) "></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess that's the effect I need. I was hoping it was possible to modify the filter and not circle element though. Thank you again! ps- I have not posted much on here, so I can't upvote you :/, but I did give you the correct answer!

Comment: All the filter sees is a bitmap representation of the element you passed it. It only has the pixels to operate on. Not the original vectors.